Unity Input System does not work with Steam opened
I'm making a multiplayer game in Unity and I'm using facepunch.Steamworks for the multiplayer. I made a quick virtual cursor to use in my lobby, so that I can move my cursor with controller. Problem is Steamworks creates some problems with my controller's connection (as if steam and an Input System component fight for the controller ownership) and as soon as my game connects with Steam, my controller gets disconnected. I found the same issue here.
I made a similar post in unity discussion and a person replied he never had this problem while working with steamworks. It's my first time using Steamworks I dont really know how to move from here
